# Port forwarding while preserving original IP

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, port-forwarding, firewalld

Im using firewalld to forward an incoming port from the internet (9999) to a local LAN IP address (100.1.1.1) like this:

```
external (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: tailscale0
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports: 9999/tcp
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp0s3
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 9999/tcp
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
port=9999:proto=tcp:toport=9999:toaddr=100.1.1.1
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules
```

The LAN IP (100.1.1.1) is from a Tailscale (VPN) interface running on the same machine, which delivers the traffic over the Internet to another machine.

The forwarding works fine, but my problem is that at the destination machine, all traffic appears to be coming from 100.1.1.1 (Tailscale) instead of the original source IP's. This is unhandy for things like fail2ban or statistics.

Is there a way to preserve the source address while still allowing the traffic to be forwarded?

EDIT: According to this article https://mghadam.blogspot.com/2020/05/forward-traffic-from-public-ip-to.html?m=1 it should be possible, but complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Disable masquerade in the external zone and forwarding to port 9999 will go the classic way, as usual in many routers, and you will see the true client addresses.

Disable masquerade command:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=external --remove-masquerade
```

If you need to share internet for the External zone, enable masquerade for Public:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-masquerade
```